# Custom PowerShell prompts

Tags: powershell, prompt

I'm looking for different examples of custom Powershell `prompt` function implementations.  If you have a custom implementation of your own please post the script.  Links to existing resources are good as well.

Bonus points for posting a screenshot of what your prompt actually looks like (a preview).

Answer (score 11):

This is modified version of jaykul's prompt. The benefit is that

-there is a current history id, so you can invoke previous items from history very easily (you know the id)
-it's a little reminder - I add my tasks to the prompt so I don't forget them (see the sshot)

```
function prompt {
  $err = !$?
  $origOfs = $ofs;
  $ofs = "|"
  $toPrompt = "$($global:__PromptVars)"
  $ofs = $origOfs;
  if ($toPrompt.Length -gt 0) { 
    Write-Host "$($toPrompt) >" -ForegroundColor Green -NoNewline }

  $host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = "PS1 > " + $(get-location)

  # store the current color, and change the color of the prompt text
  $script:fg = $Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor
  # If there's an error, set the prompt foreground to "Red"
  if($err) { $Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = 'Red' }
  else { $Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = 'Yellow' }

  # Make sure that Windows and .Net know where we are at all times
  [Environment]::CurrentDirectory = (Get-Location -PSProvider FileSystem).ProviderPath

  # Determine what nesting level we are at (if any)
  $Nesting = "$([char]0xB7)" * $NestedPromptLevel

  # Generate PUSHD(push-location) Stack level string
  $Stack = "+" * (Get-Location -Stack).count

  # Put the ID of the command in, so we can get/invoke-history easier
  # eg: "r 4" will re-run the command that has [4]: in the prompt
  $nextCommandId = (Get-History -count 1).Id + 1
  # Output prompt string
  # Notice: no angle brackets, makes it easy to paste my buffer to the web
  Write-Host "[${Nesting}${nextCommandId}${Stack}]:" -NoNewLine

  # Set back the color
  $Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = $script:fg

  if ($toPrompt.Length -gt 0) { 
      $host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = "$($toPrompt) -- " + $host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle
  }
  " "
}
function AddTo-Prompt($str) {
  if (!$global:__PromptVars) { $global:__PromptVars = @() }
  $global:__PromptVars += $str
}
function RemoveFrom-Prompt($str) {
  if ($global:__PromptVars) {
    $global:__PromptVars = @($global:__PromptVars | ? { $_ -notlike $str })
  }
}
```

[image: sshot]

Comment: The idea of putting task breadcrumbs on the prompt is very interesting. I may incorporate that into my prompt. ... 

Looks like a typo on the first Write-Host. The 'Newline' should be '-NoNewline' as in the following: Write-Host "$($toPrompt) >" -ForegroundColor Green -NoNewline }

Comment: lovelly ! I added current directory tho.

Answer (score 11):

Here's [mine](http://winterdom.com/2008/08/mypowershellprompt):

```
function prompt {
   # our theme
   $cdelim = [ConsoleColor]::DarkCyan
   $chost = [ConsoleColor]::Green
   $cloc = [ConsoleColor]::Cyan

   write-host "$([char]0x0A7) " -n -f $cloc
   write-host ([net.dns]::GetHostName()) -n -f $chost
   write-host ' {' -n -f $cdelim
   write-host (shorten-path (pwd).Path) -n -f $cloc
   write-host '}' -n -f $cdelim
   return ' '
}
```

It uses this helper function:

```
function shorten-path([string] $path) {
   $loc = $path.Replace($HOME, '~')
   # remove prefix for UNC paths
   $loc = $loc -replace '^[^:]+::', ''
   # make path shorter like tabs in Vim,
   # handle paths starting with \\ and . correctly
   return ($loc -replace '\\(\.?)([^\\])[^\\]*(?=\\)','\$1$2')
}
```

Comment: I love the format of this prompt, short and simple. It is also a great starting point for customizing your own prompt when you are just starting to learn PS like me :D

Answer (score 10):

Here is my prompt function

```
function prompt() {
    if ( Test-Wow64 ) {
        write-host -NoNewLine "Wow64 "
    }
    if ( Test-Admin ) { 
        write-host -NoNewLine -f red "Admin "
    }
    write-host -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor Green $(get-location)
    foreach ( $entry in (get-location -stack)) {
        write-host -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor Red '+';
    }
    write-host -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor Green '>'
    ' '
}
```

Comment: `Write-Host -NoNewLine -Fore Red ('+' * (Get-Location -Stack).Count)`? :-)

Comment: @Johannes, that adds a series of +'s to the prompt indicating how deep in the push stack I am

Comment: I know, I just eliminated the foreach, since you actually don't need every individual item but just the number of items.

Comment: @Johannes, ah gotcha.  Need more coffee

Answer (score 4):

i often use posh as a calc, so i set $ans variable.
https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=386493

PS > 100
100
PS > $ans * 9
900
PS > $ans*$ans
810000

Comment: What does Get-LastLine look like? I get an error: Get-LastLine : The term 'Get-LastLine' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Here's mine. Just has the history ID at each command so I can easily identify the ID of the command. I also use the windowtitle to give me the current working directory rather than have it displayed in the prompt itself.

```
106 >  cat function:\prompt

    $history = @(get-history)
    if($history.Count -gt 0)
{
        $lastItem = $history[$history.Count - 1]
        $lastId = $lastItem.Id
    }

    $nextCommand = $lastId + 1
    $Host.ui.rawui.windowtitle = "PS " + $(get-location)
    $myPrompt = "$nextCommand > "
    if ($NestedPromptLevel -gt 0) {$arrows = ">"*$NestedPromptLevel; $myPrompt = "PS-nested $arrows"}
    Write-Host ($myPrompt) -nonewline
    return " "
```

One thing that many people forget is to deal with in custom prompts is the nested prompt. Note that I check $nestedPromptLevel and add an arrow for each nested level.

Andy

Answer (score 0):

I tend to re-type

```
function prompt { "PS> " }
```

every time I am preparing examples I can copy/paste to someone, especially when I'm in cumbersome long paths which would only distract.

And I still plan to write a decent prompt function which shows me the drive and a useful approximation on the location by either using the current directory (without the path that led to there) or (if it's numeric) the next higher level too. But that's probably pretty specific to my own filesystem here. And I never was bothered enough by the default prompt to actually do it :-)