# PowerShell switch between multiple prompt functions and scoping

Tags: powershell, scope, prompt

I have found the following behaviour that I do not understand. I have some functions in my `$profile` (specifically, that change my `prompt`, so `function prmopt { }`) with settings that change my prompt and when I start a console, if I dotsource the function (  `. PromptCustom`  ), it takes full effect and the new prompt takes over. However, I don't want my `$profile` to be too big so I moved my five or so different prompts into a Module, but when I try to dotsource any of them, nothing happens. They just output what the prompt might look like but do *not* take over as the default `prompt`.

The objective is to be able to have multiple functions that switch between prompts as required (i.e. not a single prompt that applies to every console, for which I would just put `function prompt` in my `$profile`). When I move functions that follow the below template to a Module, they all break and so I was wondering if that was a scoping issue, and how to achieve the goal of having mutltiple prompt functions in a Module that I can switch between instead of being forced to keep them in my `$profile`? (Edit: updating this question as @mklement0 pointed out, since really it's about the required objective i.e. having prompts that I can switch between).

Here is one of my prompt functions that dotsources and takes over as the default prompt *perfectly* if this function is defined in my `$profile` but does nothing if it is put into a Module:

```
function PromptShortenPath {
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338453/custom-powershell-prompts
    function shorten-path([string] $path) {
        $loc = $path.Replace($HOME, '~')
        # remove prefix for UNC paths
        $loc = $loc -replace '^[^:]+::', ''
        # make path shorter like tabs in Vim,
        # handle paths starting with \\ and . correctly
        return ($loc -replace '\\(\.?)([^\\])[^\\]*(?=\\)','\$1$2')
    }
    function prompt {
        # our theme
        $cdelim = [ConsoleColor]::DarkCyan
        $chost = [ConsoleColor]::Green
        $cloc = [ConsoleColor]::Cyan

        write-host "$([char]0x0A7) " -n -f $cloc
        write-host ([net.dns]::GetHostName()) -n -f $chost
        write-host ' {' -n -f $cdelim
        write-host (shorten-path (pwd).Path) -n -f $cloc
        write-host '}' -n -f $cdelim
        return ' '
    }

    if ($MyInvocation.InvocationName -eq "PromptShortenPath") {
        "`nWarning: Must dotsource '$($MyInvocation.MyCommand)' or it will not be applied to this session.`n`n   . $($MyInvocation.MyCommand)`n"
    } else {
        . prompt 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Scepticalist's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60660760/45375) provides an effective solution for activating your `prompt` function *at the time of import*.

The approach in your question for activating the function *on demand*, by later dot-sourcing a function in which the `prompt` function is *nested*, fundamentally cannot work *as written* if that function is imported *from a module*, as explained next; **for a solution, see the bottom section**.

As for **what you tried**:

> `. prompt`

This doesn't dot-source the *definition* of function `prompt`, it *runs* the function in the sourcing scope.

- In effect, it (pointlessly) prints (once, as output) what the prompt string should be and makes the function-local variables linger in the caller's scope.

Therefore, by *nesting* the `prompt` function definition inside the `PromptShortenPath` function, dot-sourcing *that* defines the `prompt` function in the caller's scope *automatically*, along with the `shorten-path` function<sup>[1]</sup>

- If your `PromptShortenPath` function is defined *outside of a module*, dot-sourcing it means that the *sourcing* scope is the (non-module) *caller's current scope*, which defines the nested functions there, and with the appearance of a new `prompt` function, the interactive prompt string changes, as intended.
- By contrast, if your `PromptShortenPath` function is defined *inside a module*, dot-sourcing it means that the sourcing scope is the *module of origin*, which means that the *caller's* current scope is *unaffected*, and never sees the nested `shorten-path` and `prompt` functions - thus, the interactive prompt string does *not* change.

  - This bears repeating: dot-sourcing a *function* (as opposed to a *script*) runs the function in the current scope of the *scope domain of origin* rather than the *caller's* current scope; that is, dot-sourcing a function from a module invariably runs it in *that module's* current scope, which is distinct from and unrelated to the *caller's* scope (unless the caller happens to be the top-level scope inside the same module).

By contrast, Scepticalist's solution, by making `shorten-path` and `prompt` functions *top-level* functions of the module, implicitly (exports and) imports them both into the caller's scope with `Import-Module`, and, again, the appearance of a new `prompt` function in the caller's scope changes the interactive prompt string, albeit *at the time of importing*.

---

#### Alternative approach that also works with modules:

The simplest solution is to define the nested function with scope specifier `global:`, which directly defines it in the global scope, irrespective of what scope contains the definition.

As a beneficial side effect, you then no longer have to dot-source the prompt-activating function on invocation.

Note that the solution below *embeds* helper function `shorten-path` in the `global:prompt` function to ensure its availability to the latter; the alternative would be to define `shorten-path` as `global:shorten-path` too, but there is no need to clutter the global scope with helper functions, especially given that name collisions can occur.

```
# Use a dynamic module to simulate importing the `Set-Prompt` function
# from a (regular, persisted) module.
$null = New-Module {

  function Set-Prompt {

    # Note the `global:` prefix.
    Function global:prompt {
      # Note the *embedded* definition of helper function shorten-path,
      # which makes it available to the enclosing function only and avoids
      # the need to make the helper function global too.
      Function shorten-path([string] $path) {
        $loc = $path.Replace($HOME, '~')
        # remove prefix for UNC paths
        $loc = $loc -replace '^[^:]+::', ''
        # make path shorter like tabs in Vim,
        # handle paths starting with \\ and . correctly
        return ($loc -replace '\\(\.?)([^\\])[^\\]*(?=\\)', '\$1$2')
      }

      # our theme
      $cdelim = [ConsoleColor]::DarkCyan
      $chost = [ConsoleColor]::Green
      $cloc = [ConsoleColor]::Cyan

      Write-Host "$([char]0x0A7) " -n -f $cloc
      Write-Host ([net.dns]::GetHostName()) -n -f $chost
      Write-Host ' {' -n -f $cdelim
      Write-Host (shorten-path (pwd).Path) -n -f $cloc
      Write-Host '}' -n -f $cdelim
      return ' '
    }

  }

} 

# Now that Set-Prompt is imported, invoke it as you would
# any function, and the embedded `prompt` function will take effect.
Set-Prompt
```

---

<sup>[1] Note that while `shorten-path` follows PowerShell's noun-verb naming convention in principle, `shorten` is not on the list of [approved verbs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands).</sup>

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the outer function and save as modulename.psm1 in a folder by the same name within a module path:

```
Function shorten-path([string] $path) {
    $loc = $path.Replace($HOME, '~')
    # remove prefix for UNC paths
    $loc = $loc -replace '^[^:]+::', ''
    # make path shorter like tabs in Vim,
    # handle paths starting with \\ and . correctly
    return ($loc -replace '\\(\.?)([^\\])[^\\]*(?=\\)','\$1$2')
}
Function prompt {
    # our theme
    $cdelim = [ConsoleColor]::DarkCyan
    $chost = [ConsoleColor]::Green
    $cloc = [ConsoleColor]::Cyan

    write-host "$([char]0x0A7) " -n -f $cloc
    write-host ([net.dns]::GetHostName()) -n -f $chost
    write-host ' {' -n -f $cdelim
    write-host (shorten-path (pwd).Path) -n -f $cloc
    write-host '}' -n -f $cdelim
    return ' '
}
```

Now just:

```
Import-Module modulename
```

Note that the new prompt now takes effect upon importing the function

Answer (score 0):

I've finally come down to the following solution. Thanks for  helping with this @mklement / @Scepticalist. In the end, I really only needed the `global:` invocation. I didn't want a dynamic function (though interesting to see that, will probably be useful) and I did not want the prompt to activate upon importing the module (this was explicitly what I wanted to avoid in fact!).

All of these now work by dropping into any personal Module. Importing the Module will *not* activate the prompt (this was my desired outcome). Each prompt can then be activated on demand simply by invoking the function that sets that prompt (or its alias).

**Edit:** Please feel free to add any more prompt functions that do interesting things. I'm always very interested in seeing more useful tricks and variations for prompt configurations! :)

```
function PromptDefault {
    # get-help about_Prompt
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_prompts?view=powershell-7
    function global:prompt {
        "PS $($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) ";
        # .Link
        # https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=225750
        # .ExternalHelp System.Management.Automation.dll-help.xml

        $Elevated = ""
        $user = [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent();
        if ((New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal $user).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltinRole]::Administrator)) {$Elevated = "Administrator: "}
        # $TitleVer = "PS v$($PSVersionTable.PSversion.major).$($PSVersionTable.PSversion.minor)"
        $TitleVer = "PowerShell"
        $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = "$($Elevated)$($TitleVer)"
    }
}

# More simple alternative prompt, need to dotsource this
function PromptTimeUptime {
    function global:prompt {
        # Adds date/time to prompt and uptime to title bar
        $Elevated = "" ; if (Test-Admin) {$Elevated = "Administrator: "}
        $up = Uptime
        $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = $Elevated + "PowerShell [Uptime: $up]"   # Title bar info
        $path = Get-Location
        Write-Host '[' -NoNewline
        Write-Host (Get-Date -UFormat '%T') -ForegroundColor Green -NoNewline   # $TitleDate = Get-Date -format "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
        Write-Host '] ' -NoNewline
        Write-Host "$path" -NoNewline
        return "> "   # Must have a line like this at end of prompt or you always get " PS>" on the prompt
    }
}

function PromptTruncatedPaths {
    # https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/05/12/customizing-the-powershell-command-prompt/
    function global:prompt {
        $cwd = (get-location).Path
        [array]$cwdt=$()
        $cwdi = -1
        do {$cwdi = $cwd.indexofany("\", $cwdi+1) ; [array]$cwdt+=$cwdi} until($cwdi -eq -1)
        if ($cwdt.count -gt 3) { $cwd = $cwd.substring(0,$cwdt[0]) + ".." + $cwd.substring($cwdt[$cwdt.count-3]) }
        $host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = "$(hostname) – $env:USERDNSDOMAIN$($env:username)"
        $host.UI.Write("Yellow", $host.UI.RawUI.BackGroundColor, "[PS]")
        " $cwd> "
    }
}

function PromptShortenPath {
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338453/custom-powershell-prompts
    function global:shorten-path([string] $path) {
        $loc = $path.Replace($HOME, '~')
        # remove prefix for UNC paths
        $loc = $loc -replace '^[^:]+::', ''
        # make path shorter like tabs in Vim,
        # handle paths starting with \\ and . correctly
        return ($loc -replace '\\(\.?)([^\\])[^\\]*(?=\\)','\$1$2')
    }
    function global:prompt {
        # our theme
        $cdelim = [ConsoleColor]::DarkCyan
        $chost = [ConsoleColor]::Green
        $cloc = [ConsoleColor]::Cyan

        write-host "$([char]0x0A7) " -n -f $cloc
        write-host ([net.dns]::GetHostName()) -n -f $chost
        write-host ' {' -n -f $cdelim
        write-host (shorten-path (pwd).Path) -n -f $cloc
        write-host '}' -n -f $cdelim
        return ' '
    }
}

function PromptUserAndExecutionTimer {
    function global:prompt {

        ### Title bar info
        $user = [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent();
        $Elevated = ""
        if ((New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal $user).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltinRole]::Administrator)) {$Elevated = "Admin: "}
        $TitleVer = "PS v$($PSVersionTable.PSversion.major).$($PSVersionTable.PSversion.minor)"
        # $($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation.path)

        ### Custom Uptime without seconds (not really necessary)
        # $wmi = gwmi -class Win32_OperatingSystem -computer "."
        # $LBTime = $wmi.ConvertToDateTime($wmi.Lastbootuptime)
        # [TimeSpan]$uptime = New-TimeSpan $LBTime $(get-date)
        # $s = "" ; if ($uptime.Days -ne 1) {$s = "s"}
        # $TitleUp = "[Up: $($uptime.days) day$s $($uptime.hours) hr $($uptime.minutes) min]"

        $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = "$($Elevated) $($TitleVer)"   # $($TitleUp)"

        ### History ID
        $HistoryId = $MyInvocation.HistoryId
        # Uncomment below for leading zeros
        # $HistoryId = '{0:d4}' -f $MyInvocation.HistoryId
        Write-Host -Object "$HistoryId " -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Cyan


        ### Time calculation
        $Success = $?
        $LastExecutionTimeSpan = if (@(Get-History).Count -gt 0) {
            Get-History | Select-Object -Last 1 | ForEach-Object {
                New-TimeSpan -Start $_.StartExecutionTime -End $_.EndExecutionTime
            }
        }
        else {
            New-TimeSpan
        }

        $LastExecutionShortTime = if ($LastExecutionTimeSpan.Days -gt 0) {
            "$($LastExecutionTimeSpan.Days + [Math]::Round($LastExecutionTimeSpan.Hours / 24, 2)) d"
        }
        elseif ($LastExecutionTimeSpan.Hours -gt 0) {
            "$($LastExecutionTimeSpan.Hours + [Math]::Round($LastExecutionTimeSpan.Minutes / 60, 2)) h"
        }
        elseif ($LastExecutionTimeSpan.Minutes -gt 0) {
            "$($LastExecutionTimeSpan.Minutes + [Math]::Round($LastExecutionTimeSpan.Seconds / 60, 2)) m"
        }
        elseif ($LastExecutionTimeSpan.Seconds -gt 0) {
            "$($LastExecutionTimeSpan.Seconds + [Math]::Round($LastExecutionTimeSpan.Milliseconds / 1000, 1)) s"
        }
        elseif ($LastExecutionTimeSpan.Milliseconds -gt 0) {
            "$([Math]::Round($LastExecutionTimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds, 0)) ms"
            # ms are 1/1000 of a sec so no point in extra decimal places here
        }
        else {
            "0 s"
        }

        if ($Success) {
            Write-Host -Object "[$LastExecutionShortTime] " -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Green
        }
        else {
            Write-Host -Object "! [$LastExecutionShortTime] " -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Red
        }

        ### User, removed
        $IsAdmin = (New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal ([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltinRole]::Administrator)
        # Write-Host -Object "$($env:USERNAME)$(if ($IsAdmin){ '[A]' } else { '[U]' }) " -NoNewline -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
        # Write-Host -Object "$($env:USERNAME)" -NoNewline -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
        # Write-Host -Object " [" -NoNewline
        # if ($IsAdmin) { Write-Host -Object 'A' -NoNewline -F Red } else { Write-Host -Object 'U' -NoNewline }
        # Write-Host -Object "] " -NoNewline
        Write-Host "$($env:USERNAME)" -NoNewline -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
        Write-Host "[" -NoNewline
        if ($IsAdmin) { Write-Host 'A' -NoNewline -F Red } else { Write-Host -Object 'U' -NoNewline }
        Write-Host "] " -NoNewline

        # ### Path
        # $Drive = $pwd.Drive.Name
        # $Pwds = $pwd -split "\\" | Where-Object { -Not [String]::IsNullOrEmpty($_) }
        # $PwdPath = if ($Pwds.Count -gt 3) {
        #     $ParentFolder = Split-Path -Path (Split-Path -Path $pwd -Parent) -Leaf
        #     $CurrentFolder = Split-Path -Path $pwd -Leaf
        #     "..\$ParentFolder\$CurrentFolder"
        # go  # }
        # elseif ($Pwds.Count -eq 3) {
        #     $ParentFolder = Split-Path -Path (Split-Path -Path $pwd -Parent) -Leaf
        #     $CurrentFolder = Split-Path -Path $pwd -Leaf
        #     "$ParentFolder\$CurrentFolder"
        # }
        # elseif ($Pwds.Count -eq 2) {
        #     Split-Path -Path $pwd -Leaf
        # }
        # else { "" }
        # Write-Host -Object "$Drive`:\$PwdPath" -NoNewline

        Write-Host $pwd -NoNewline
        return "> "
    }
}

function PromptSlightlyBroken {
    # https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1965997-custom-cmd-powershell-prompt

    # if ($MyInvocation.InvocationName -eq "PromptOverTheTop") {
    #     "`nWarning: Must dotsource '$($MyInvocation.MyCommand)' or it will not be applied to this session.`n`n   . $($MyInvocation.MyCommand)`n"
    # } else {
    if ($host.name -eq 'ConsoleHost') {
        # fff
        $Shell = $Host.UI.RawUI
        $Shell.BackgroundColor = "Black"
        $Shell.ForegroundColor = "White"
        $Shell.CursorSize = 10
    }
    # $Shell=$Host.UI.RawUI
    # $size=$Shell.BufferSize
    # $size.width=120
    # $size.height=3000
    # $Shell.BufferSize=$size
    # $size=$Shell.WindowSize
    # $size.width=120
    # $size.height=30
    # $Shell.WindowSize=$size
    # $Shell.BackgroundColor="Black"
    # $Shell.ForegroundColor="White"
    # $Shell.CursorSize=10
    # $Shell.WindowTitle="Console PowerShell"

    function global:Get-Uptime {
        $os = Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem
        $uptime = (Get-Date) - ($os.ConvertToDateTime($os.lastbootuptime))
        $days = $Uptime.Days ; if ($days -eq "1") { $days = "$days day" } else { $days = "$days days"}
        $hours = $Uptime.Hours ; if ($hours -eq "1") { $hours = "$hours hr" } else { $hours = "$hours hrs"}
        $minutes = $Uptime.Minutes ; if ($minutes -eq "1") { $minutes = "$minutes min" } else { $minutes = "$minutes mins"}
        $Display = "$days, $hours, $minutes"
        Write-Output $Display
    }
    function Spaces ($numspaces) { for ($i = 0; $i -lt $numspaces; $i++) { Write-Host " " -NoNewline } }

    # $MaximumHistoryCount=1024
    $IPAddress = @(Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Where-Object {$_.DefaultIpGateway})[0].IPAddress[0]
    $IPGateway = @(Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Where-Object {$_.DefaultIpGateway})[0].DefaultIPGateway[0]
    $UserDetails = "$env:UserDomain\$env:UserName (PS-HOME: $HOME)"
    $PSExecPolicy = Get-ExecutionPolicy
    $PSVersion = "$($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major).$($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Minor) ($PSExecPolicy)"
    $ComputerAndLogon = "$($env:COMPUTERNAME)"
    $ComputerAndLogonSpaces = 28 - $ComputerAndLogon.Length
    Clear
    Write-Host "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" -ForegroundColor Green
    Write-Host "|    ComputerName:  " -nonewline -ForegroundColor Green; Write-Host $ComputerAndLogon -nonewline -ForegroundColor White ; Spaces $ComputerAndLogonSpaces ; Write-Host "UserName:" -nonewline -ForegroundColor Green ; Write-Host "  $UserDetails" -ForegroundColor White
    Write-Host "|    Logon Server:  " -nonewline -ForegroundColor Green; Write-Host $($env:LOGONSERVER)"`t`t`t`t" -nonewline -ForegroundColor White ; Write-Host "IP Address:`t" -nonewline -ForegroundColor Green ; Write-Host "`t$IPAddress ($IPGateway)" -ForegroundColor White
    Write-Host "|    Uptime:        " -nonewline -ForegroundColor Green; Write-Host "$(Get-Uptime)`t" -nonewline -ForegroundColor White; Write-Host "PS Version:`t" -nonewline -ForegroundColor Green ; Write-Host "`t$PSVersion" -ForegroundColor White
    Write-Host "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" -ForegroundColor Green
    # Write-Host "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" -ForegroundColor Green
    # Write-Host "|`tComputerName:`t" -nonewline -ForegroundColor Green; Write-Host $($env:COMPUTERNAME)"`t`t`t`t" -nonewline -ForegroundColor White ; Write-Host "UserName:`t$UserDetails" -ForegroundColor White
    # Write-Host "|`tLogon Server:`t" -nonewline -ForegroundColor Green; Write-Host $($env:LOGONSERVER)"`t`t`t`t" -nonewline -ForegroundColor White ; Write-Host "IP Address:`t$IPAddress ($IPGateway)" -ForegroundColor White
    # Write-Host "|`tUptime:`t`t" -nonewline -ForegroundColor Green; Write-Host "$(Get-Uptime)`t" -nonewline -ForegroundColor White; Write-Host "PS Version:`t$PSVersion" -ForegroundColor White
    # Write-Host "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" -ForegroundColor Green
    function global:admin {
        $Elevated = ""
        $currentPrincipal = New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal( [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent() )
        if ($currentPrincipal.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator) -eq $true) { $Elevated = "Administrator: " }
        $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = "$Elevated$TitleVer"
    }
    admin
    Set-Location C:\

    function global:prompt{
        $br = "`n"
        Write-Host "[" -noNewLine
        Write-Host $(Get-date) -ForegroundColor Green -noNewLine
        Write-Host "] " -noNewLine
        Write-Host "[" -noNewLine
        Write-Host "$env:username" -Foregroundcolor Red -noNewLine
        Write-Host "] " -noNewLine
        Write-Host "[" -noNewLine
        Write-Host $($(Get-Location).Path.replace($home,"~")) -ForegroundColor Yellow -noNewLine
        Write-Host $(if ($nestedpromptlevel -ge 1) { '>>' }) -noNewLine
        Write-Host "] "
        return "> "
    }
}

Set-Alias p0 PromptDefault
Set-Alias p-default PromptDefault
Set-Alias p-timer PromptUserAndExecutionTimer   # Using this as my console default
Set-Alias p-short PromptShortenPath
Set-Alias p-trunc PromptTruncatedPaths 
Set-Alias p-uptime PromptTimeUptime
Set-Alias p-broken PromptSlightlyBroken

# View current prompt with: (get-item function:prompt).scriptblock   or   cat function:\prompt
```